# Legendre transform is everywhere finite iff $ f$ grows faster than $ 2$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}\cup \{ \infty \}$ be convex.  Its Legendre transform is $f^* (d):=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}(d^Tx-f(x))$ 
Show $f^*(d)<\infty$ $\forall d\in \mathbb{R}^n$ iff $\exists r:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\lim_{t\to \infty}r(t)=\infty$ and $f(x)\geq r(||x||_2)$.

This claim was made in some notes on convex fns I am reading.  While this fact seems intuitive, I'm having trouble proving it. 
The direction I am going right now (w/o luck) is to show that : $\exists d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $f^*(d)=\infty$ ($\forall t\in \mathbb{R}, \exists\in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $f(x)<d^T x-t$) iff $\exists M>0$ s.t. $\forall R>0,\exists x\in \mathbb{R}^n,||x||_2>R$ s.t. $f(x)<M||x||_2$.

Comment: This is wrong as stated, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427317/confusion-with-finiteness-of-the-legendre-transform/3427327#3427327

Answer (score 1):

($\Longleftarrow$) Suppose there exists a function $r: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such  that $\underset{t \rightarrow +\infty}{\text{lim }}r(t) = +\infty$ and $f(x) \ge r(\|x\|_2)$ for sufficiently large $x$. Then given any $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the existence of $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) \ge r(\|x\|_2) \ge \|d\|_2\|x\|_2$ whenever $\|x\|_2 > \delta$, is guarenteed. Thus by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $d^Tx - f(x) \le \|d\|_2 \|x\|_2 - f(x) \le 0$ if $\|x\| > \delta$. Hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
 f^*(d) = \text{max }\left\{\underset{\|x\|_2 \le \delta}{\text{sup }}d^Tx - f(x), \underset{\|x\|_2 > \delta}{\text{sup }}d^Tx - f(x)\right\} &\le \text{max }\left\{\underset{\|x\|_2 \le \delta}{\text{sup }}d^Tx - f(x), 0\right\} \\
&< +\infty.
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks for one direction!  I had a feeling it involved Cauchy-Schwarz somehow.  I would love to accept your answer if you have the other direction.